# Delete not working for Vue Route against API

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to setup a basic system where I can edit and delete values from a table. Been following a couple of guides and have hit a stumbling block.

```
<tbody>
<tr v-for="(product,index) in products" @key="index">
     <td>{{index+1}}</td>
     <td v-html="product.name"></td>
     <td v-model="product.units">{{product.units}}</td>
     <td v-model="product.price">{{product.price}}</td>
     <td v-model="product.price">{{product.description}}</td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="editingItem = product">Edit</button></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="deleteProduct(product)">Delete</button></td>
```

The second button then calls a deleteProduct method, and supplies the product for deletion.

```
    deleteProduct(product) {
        let id = product.id
        let units = product.units
        let price = product.price
        let description = product.description
        let image = product.image 
        axios.delete("/api/products/", {name, units, price, description, image})
            .then(response => this.products.shift(product))

    }
```

Axios makes a call on the ProductController's destroy method.

```
public function destroy(Product $product)
{
    $status = $product->delete();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $status ? 'Product Deleted!' : 'Error Deleting Product'
    ]);
}
```

And then lastly I have the API routes.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::get('/users','UserController@index');
    Route::get('users/{user}','UserController@show');
    Route::patch('users/{user}','UserController@update');
    Route::get('users/{user}/orders','UserController@showOrders');
    Route::patch('products/{product}/units/add','ProductController@updateUnits');
    Route::patch('orders/{order}/deliver','OrderController@deliverOrder');
    Route::resource('/orders', 'OrderController');
    Route::resource('/products', 'ProductController')->except(['index','show']);
});
```

The last route is a resource from the ProductController, so it should give me all suitable methods. Using route:list also shows me that all of the routes have been setup correctly.

[image: Route::List]

This issue comes when I actually try and delete a entry. All I get in return is a 405 error, which provides the following error.

The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

However I can clearly see DELETE method in route:list. Would anyone just be able to clarify if I am missing something obvious here, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 deleteProduct(product) {
    let id = product.id
    let units = product.units
    let price = product.price
    let description = product.description
    let image = product.image 
    axios.delete("/api/products/" + product.id)
       .then(response => this.products.shift(product))

 }
```

You are missing product id in your ajax call. You should use `/api/products/{id}`

Comment: That works perfectly thank you!! For my addProduct I am using the same kind of syntax in my ajax call.

axios.post("/api/products/", {name, units, price, description, image})
                 .then(response => this.products.push(product))

Would this need to be changed as well? As I noticed it does not actually create a new entry in the DB.

Comment: you should write what are you posting in axios.post('/api/products', {name: 'BMW X6'})

Comment: I mean key value